# VLC sound shuttering on Ubuntu Pi x64

Tags: sound, 20.04, vlc, raspberrypi

I'm new here and starting my fun with Raspberry pi 4 8gb.

Recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and VLC media player on it to watch movies.

The problem I have is the sound randomly shuttering (disappearing) during playback.

Video is running fine with no issues but the sound occasionally disappears for a second and comes back to normal then it happens again.

This is happening on any king of video format I play.

Tried different audio outputs but still same.

Tried increasing file cashing as suggested on a different forum, but no joy.

Tried switching off WiFi as someone suggested on another forum but again no joy.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Mayby try shutting down heavy programs, i also had this problem when running heavy games.
(edit) mayby there is a heavy program running without you knowing it. For more info, please visit [this](https://vitux.com/4-ways-to-kill-unresponsive-applications-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: I am running fresh Ubuntu, installed few days ago, there is literally nothing on it yet apart from VLC and samba. When I check system monitor nothing seems to be using resources heavily so there is nothing to kill. Can anyone tell what video/audio outputs configuration should I use on VLC? Maybe this is going to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didnt look at your complete question, what i think you are doing wrong, is installing ubuntu on a raspberry pi. You can try visiting https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/ for raspberry pi OS, wich is made for an raspberry pi.

Comment: I've been using raspian od for a while and considered installing Ubuntu as it is compatible now with arm architecture and supporting x64, while standard raspbian don't. This was the reason for swapping and I can see quite a difference in performance. I can still use raspbian as it is installed on my sd card, while Ubuntu is running on external SSD.

Comment: @jerry what i learned, was that ubuntu with an raspberry pi may not get the drivers to work functionally.

Comment: thanks for this I will consider using it for a while and test it my own. If I find any good solution I will update this thread.